# Spark program hangs at Job finished: toArray - workers throw java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have a simple spark job where I'm trying to work out how to write bytes into a sequence file.  It was working fine, then suddenly the job hangs seemingly at the end - in particular at this line:

```
14/06/06 10:57:48 INFO SparkContext: Job finished: toArray at XXXX.scala:104, took 44.439736728 s
```

So I had a look at the stderr logs on the workers and I see this:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.askDriverWithReply(BlockManagerMaster.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.sendHeartBeat(BlockManagerMaster.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$heartBeat(BlockManager.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$initialize$1.apply$mcV$sp(BlockManager.scala:135)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$9.run(Scheduler.scala:80)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3$$anon$2.run(Scheduler.scala:241)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The job output has some weird INFO messages I've not seen before:

```
14/06/06 11:08:28 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 2 in 2163 ms on ip-172-31-23-17.ec2.internal (progress: 0/5)
14/06/06 11:08:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(1, 0)
14/06/06 11:08:30 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 3 in 3635 ms on ip-172-31-29-86.ec2.internal (progress: 1/5)
14/06/06 11:08:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(1, 1)

^^ Normal output see this in jobs all the time.  But below lots of weird messages.

14/06/06 11:08:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_6 in memory on ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal:41661 (size: 253.9 MB, free: 2.6 GB)
14/06/06 11:08:50 INFO SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal/172.31.30.95:41661]
14/06/06 11:08:50 INFO SendingConnection: Connected to [ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal/172.31.30.95:41661], 1 messages pending
14/06/06 11:08:50 INFO ConnectionManager: Accepted connection from [ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal/172.31.30.95]
14/06/06 11:08:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 6 in 25831 ms on ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal (progress: 2/5)
14/06/06 11:08:52 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_6 on ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal:41661 in memory (size: 253.9 MB, free: 2.9 GB)
14/06/06 11:08:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(1, 4)
14/06/06 11:08:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_4 in memory on ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal:46736 (size: 329.3 MB, free: 2.6 GB)
14/06/06 11:08:57 INFO SendingConnection: Initiating connection to [ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal/172.31.22.58:46736]
14/06/06 11:08:57 INFO SendingConnection: Connected to [ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal/172.31.22.58:46736], 1 messages pending
14/06/06 11:08:57 INFO ConnectionManager: Accepted connection from [ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal/172.31.22.58]
14/06/06 11:09:00 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 4 in 33738 ms on ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal (progress: 3/5)
14/06/06 11:09:00 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Removed taskresult_4 on ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal:46736 in memory (size: 329.3 MB, free: 2.9 GB)
14/06/06 11:09:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(1, 2)
```

If I'm then very patient, eventually the job spits out some more weird stuff:

```
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal,41661)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/9 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal,41661)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal,35129)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@6b071630
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal,35129)
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnectionManagerId not found
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal,46736)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal,46736)
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR ConnectionManager: Corresponding SendingConnectionManagerId not found
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@6b071630
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$3.run(ConnectionManager.scala:98)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/9 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR SendingConnection: Exception while reading SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal,35129)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:252)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.network.SendingConnection.read(Connection.scala:398)
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$5.run(ConnectionManager.scala:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(1, ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal, 41661, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132381ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 9 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(6, ip-172-31-17-30.ec2.internal, 43082, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132382ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Handling connection error on connection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal,35129)
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(<driver>, ip-172-31-23-17.ec2.internal, 55101, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132385ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 9 (already removed): Uncaught exception
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal,35129)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@3c39a92
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(8, ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal, 46736, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132377ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/10 on worker-20140606110717-ip-172-31-21-172.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-21-172.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@3c39a92
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$3.run(ConnectionManager.scala:98)
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(9, ip-172-31-21-172.ec2.internal, 42635, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132384ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Key not valid ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@46000f2b
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/10 on hostPort ip-172-31-21-172.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(7, ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal, 35129, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132379ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/10 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/4 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/4 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: key already cancelled ? sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@46000f2b
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.network.ConnectionManager$$anon$3.run(ConnectionManager.scala:98)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 4 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 4 on ip-172-31-28-73.ec2.internal: Uncaught exception
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal,35129)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/11 on worker-20140606110708-ip-172-31-28-73.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-28-73.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 4 (epoch 0)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/11 on hostPort ip-172-31-28-73.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/3 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/3 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 1 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 3 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 3 (already removed): Uncaught exception
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 7 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 7 on ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(2, ip-172-31-23-17.ec2.internal, 44685, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132373ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, ip-172-31-24-194.ec2.internal, 47896, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132382ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 5 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 5 on ip-172-31-29-86.ec2.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/12 on worker-20140606110708-ip-172-31-26-188.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-26-188.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(5, ip-172-31-29-86.ec2.internal, 48078, 0) with no recent heart beats: 132380ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 8 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 8 on ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/12 on hostPort ip-172-31-26-188.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to remove executor 4 from BlockManagerMaster.
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/6 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 2 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 4 successfully in removeExecutor
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/6 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 1 (epoch 1)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 1 successfully in removeExecutor
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on ip-172-31-23-17.ec2.internal: remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 7 (epoch 2)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 0 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to remove executor 7 from BlockManagerMaster.
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 0 (already removed): remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 6 disconnected, so removing it
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 7 successfully in removeExecutor
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 6 (already removed): remote Akka client disassociated
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 5 (epoch 3)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to remove executor 5 from BlockManagerMaster.
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/13 on worker-20140606110717-ip-172-31-17-30.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-17-30.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 5 successfully in removeExecutor
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/13 on hostPort ip-172-31-17-30.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 8 (epoch 4)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to remove executor 8 from BlockManagerMaster.
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 8 successfully in removeExecutor
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/11 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 2 (epoch 5)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 2 successfully in removeExecutor
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/13 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/12 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/0 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/0 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/14 on worker-20140606110706-ip-172-31-24-194.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-24-194.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/14 on hostPort ip-172-31-24-194.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/14 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/5 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/5 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/15 on worker-20140606110706-ip-172-31-29-86.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-29-86.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/15 on hostPort ip-172-31-29-86.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/15 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/1 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/1 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/16 on worker-20140606110708-ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/16 on hostPort ip-172-31-30-95.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/16 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/8 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/8 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/17 on worker-20140606110708-ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/17 on hostPort ip-172-31-22-58.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/17 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/7 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/7 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor added: app-20140606110822-0000/18 on worker-20140606110706-ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal-7078 (ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal:7078) with 8 cores
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20140606110822-0000/18 on hostPort ip-172-31-28-236.ec2.internal:7078 with 8 cores, 5.0 GB RAM
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/18 is now RUNNING
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Executor updated: app-20140606110822-0000/2 is now FAILED (Command exited with code 50)
14/06/06 11:14:15 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140606110822-0000/2 removed: Command exited with code 50
14/06/06 11:14:15 ERROR AppClient$ClientActor: Master removed our application: FAILED; stopping client
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster! Waiting for reconnection...
```

Where it just hangs again ... again if I'm patient it then spits out the following and hangs again

```
14/06/06 11:14:15 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster! Waiting for reconnection...
14/06/06 11:16:54 WARN BlockManagerMasterActor: Removing BlockManager BlockManagerId(3, ip-172-31-26-188.ec2.internal, 55392, 0) with no recent heart beats: 159686ms exceeds 45000ms
14/06/06 11:19:42 WARN BlockManagerMaster: Error sending message to BlockManagerMaster in 1 attempts
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [30 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.askDriverWithReply(BlockManagerMaster.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.sendHeartBeat(BlockManagerMaster.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$heartBeat(BlockManager.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$initialize$1.apply$mcV$sp(BlockManager.scala:135)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$9.run(Scheduler.scala:80)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$3$$anon$2.run(Scheduler.scala:241)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

After 10 mins, my patience runs out and I kill -9 it (normal interrupt doesn't work).

The question is, how do I get my cluster back to when it worked? It seems spark is holding some state somewhere which we can't zap.  We have tried deleting the spark cache files i.e. .../spark/spark-*, we have tried restarting all the workers and the master!

UPDATE:

I think the problem could be that the file I thought I was reading got corrupted in some way that meant it became about 370 MB.  The `toArray` on such a large amount of data may have caused stuff to go crazy.  After just deleting the file and trying again on other files, things returned to normal.  Nevertheless leaving the question open as the behaviour thrown isn't what one would expect - one would simply expect a long wait, followed by possibly an OOM.

Comment: Smells like a bug. You will have more luck with this on the spark mailing list: https://spark.apache.org/community.html

Comment: Turns out something went seriously wrong and the sequence file I thought I was read/writing to was over 300MB.  How this happened I have no idea.  Anyway I guess `toArray` on that much data is going to mess things up.

Comment: which version do you used?